# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.app.MyApp: java.lang.NullPointerException: FirebaseCrashlytics component is not present

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, crashlytics-android

Getting this crash on only release build with r8 enabled on migrating from crashlytics to firebase SDK and upgrading gradle plugin version

**Note : I have multidex dependencies defined and set in build.gradle and also in the application class. This happens only when i upgrade my gradle plugin version from 3.5 to 4.1**

I am using firebase-crashlytics version

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0'
```

Grade plugin version

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
```

Crashlytics gradle plugin version

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'
```

Also I am getting warning in the logcat for

```
W/ComponentDiscovery: Class com.google.firebase.crashlytics.CrashlyticsRegistrar is not an found.
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.crashlytics.CrashlyticsRegistrar

 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.crashlytics.CrashlyticsRegistrar" on path: DexPathList


W/ComponentDiscovery: Class com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar is not an found.
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar" on path: DexPathList

W/ComponentDiscovery: Class com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseRegistrar is not an found.
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseRegistrar

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseRegistrar" on path: DexPathList
```

To get rid of the above warning I added the following in android manifest under application tag

```
 <service android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService" >
      <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar"
          android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
      <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseRegistrar"
          android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"/>
      <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.crashlytics.CrashlyticsRegistrar"
          android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"/>

    </service>
```

Still no luck with it. After doing all these I see this

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.app.MyApp: java.lang.NullPointerException: FirebaseCrashlytics component is not present
```

NPE when I try to access

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance();
```

Comment: did you tried to add `Multidex`?

Comment: @Priyankagb Yes. I have already set it. Same thing works when gradle plugin version is < 4.0. This happens only when I upgrade gradle version to 4+

Comment: update version of `firebase-crashlytics` to latest and also try to add `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0'`

Comment: @Priyankagb ```implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0'``` this version is already set and if I upgrade it to the crashlytics 17.3.0 there are some other directories which are causing problem. I did that once. But not sure if that will fix it. Let me try to resolve them as well.

Comment: If it works in debug mode, it sounds like an issue with proguarding. Try to keep all your firebase classes `-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }` and rebuild see if it helps

Comment: @NitinMesta If you can provide demo project on Github, then I can help with debugging.

Comment: Do you have this line in your `build.gradle` file? `apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'`

Comment: @NitinMesta you found any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }` into proguard-rules.pro, fixed this issue.

Comment: does not fix here

Answer (score 0):

Had problem with this, looks like we have to manually register in our manifest

Insert this into your manifest:

```
  <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        tools:targetApi="n">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar"
            android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar"
            android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.crashlytics.CrashlyticsRegistrar"
            android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsRegistrar"
            android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"/>
    </service>
```

With this you will see that the application will log itself (in `adb logcat -s FirebaseCrashlytics`)

But the reports were still not being sent, looking at the output of the logs showed `Transport backend 'cct' is not registered`.

```
Crashlytics report could not be enqueued to DataTransport
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Transport backend 'cct' is not registered
      at com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.DefaultScheduler.lambda$schedule$1$DefaultScheduler(DefaultScheduler.java:77)
      at com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.-$$Lambda$DefaultScheduler$DT3VaFjNTilJSvcr2dFbjD3xxDQ.run(Unknown Source:8)
      at com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.SafeLoggingExecutor$SafeLoggingRunnable.run(SafeLoggingExecutor.java:47)
```

Then just add this information to your manifest

```
<service android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.backends.TransportBackendDiscovery">
     <meta-data android:name="backend:com.google.android.datatransport.cct.CctBackendFactory" android:value="cct"/>
</service>

<service
    android:name="com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.JobInfoSchedulerService"
    android:exported="false"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>
```

And add initialize firebase in your app in `oncreate`

```
class MyApp : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        ...
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)
    }
}
```

References: [This](https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/any-ideas-why-this-other-app-is-able-to-keep-running-during-device-stress-when-my-app-can-not.145688/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65635401/crashlytics-dont-report-crashes-in-firebase)

Hope this helps.

Comment: For me, it was the `meta-data` entry ending with `CrashlyticsRegistrar` that was the problem - adding that fixed the error

Answer (score -1):

Try adding Firebase-BOM in Gradle (app).

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.1')
```

Then in your Application class
Instead of

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance();
```

Use

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
```

Comment: That's what we do but the crash still happens.