# Crashlytics don't report crashes in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, dexguard

Application using Dexguard(8.4.9), Crashlytics(17.2.2), CrashlyticsGradle(2.3.0)
Already insert a lot of rules in dexguard-rules and not solved that.
All help will be welcome.

Logcat:

D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Checking for crash reports...
D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Found crash report /data/user/0/com.xxxxxxx/files/.com.google.firebase.crashlytics/nonfatal-sessions/5F64E11E01BD-0001-6C5D-32B9DF9F8C8E.cls
D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Reports are being sent.
D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Starting report processing in 1.0 second(s)...
D/FirebaseCrashlytics: No log data to include with this event.
D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Update app request ID: aca879994130dcc6ab3f551k2j4bjj23
D/FirebaseCrashlytics: No log data to include with this event.
D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Result was 204
D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics report could not be enqueued to DataTransport
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Transport backend 'cct' is not registered
at com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.DefaultScheduler$$Lambda$1.run(:1077)
at com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.SafeLoggingExecutor$SafeLoggingRunnable.run(:47)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)

Comment: Do you also have `-keepresourcexmlelements manifest/application/service/meta-data@value=cct` in dexguard rules?

Comment: @laalto I'm not using dexguard. What else could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem with Firebase Crashlytics you have to put in your minefest:

```
<service android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.backends.TransportBackendDiscovery">
    <meta-data android:name="backend:com.google.android.datatransport.cct.CctBackendFactory" android:value="cct"/>
</service>
```

Comment: When I add this, I'm getting a new error `IllegalArgumentException: No such service ComponentInfo{my.package.name/com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.JobInfoSchedulerService}`

Comment: @HaseebPavaratty See new answer below

Answer (score 2):

After I added this code:

```
<service android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.backends.TransportBackendDiscovery">
            <meta-data android:name="backend:com.google.android.datatransport.cct.CctBackendFactory" android:value="cct"/>
        </service>
```

I got a new error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: No such service ComponentInfo{my.package.name/com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.JobInfoSchedulerService}
```

I solved this error by adding this service to the manifest file:

```
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.JobInfoSchedulerService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" >
        </service>
```

Comment: Worked on flutter 3.3.2, thanks!